# SP2010 COM GetFolderbyURL how can I get the library of the folder?

Tags: 2010

I know the URL to a document Library folder and I am able to successfully retrieve that folder using Client Object Model GetFolder.  However, I do not know the Document Library title, how can I get the metadata of the Document Library that the folder I am on is in?
I can C# or vb.net.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that your code to GetFolder would be something like below, if yes then the code to get Document library title would be as follows:

```
string url = web.ServerRelativeUrl + "/shared documents/test folder";
SPFolder folder = web.GetFolder(url);
var docLibTitle = folder.Item.ParentList.Title;
```

Comment: Thank you; however, the code provided is for SharePoint Object Model.  I am using the Client Object Model it uses: sp.Folder Folder = web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(url library name); after getting the folder Item is not available nor ParentList.